# Is it possible to Rearrange the columns in SSRS reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008

I have a Matrix report in which the user can select a list of columns related to a particular table using a parameter. I need to rearrange the columns. I'm dealing with dynamic columns so i can't do it in designer mode.

I'm able to move & swap a single column by using two parameters one is to select a particular column we want to move and other parameter is to select a column that my desired column need to place after/before this column. For this I have created a Stored Procedure. It works fine.

Is it possible to rearrange multiple columns before viewing the report?

Comment: Are the columns that you want to rearrange within a column grouping? or are they just static columns?

Comment: within a column grouping

Comment: Are you only wanting to position one column or allow the user to completely rearrange the table to how they want? To allow multiple you would need to keep passing the positions back and forth via a hidden parameter of some sort.

Comment: i can pass the position one at a time, how can i implement on multiple columns before displaying the report

Answer (score 2):

make the sort order of a the column group a calculated statement using the parameters to determine the sort order

Comment: I've made the sort order to the column group by this we can view the columns in a particular order.In my requirement the user has to move the columns on his way

Comment: make it a user selected parameter that must be entered BEFORE they run the report.  Selection of this parameter can pass through to either A) the query, to determine the column order OR  B) the grouping expression, to dynamically manipulate the column sort based on a value passed from the parameter the user selected